# Making certain fields in the Form read only

Tags: html, django, django-forms

I would like to make certain fields in the form to read only while other editable. I read this in HTML ([Read only](http://www.w3schools.com/html5/att_input_readonly.asp))

```
<form action="demo_form.asp">
Country: <input type="text" name="country" value="Norway" readonly="readonly" /><br />
<input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

This example specifically states the fields which will be editable. But i am using Django Forms. I am not able to do this specifically because the field is derived from models.py.

What options do i have in making the fields read only? Need some suggestions and guidance...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When creating the form add an extra param to add the readonly attribute, for your field:

```
name = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'readonly':'readonly'}))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use jQuery to add the property?

```
$('.inputClass').prop("readonly", true);
```

Comment: "usually" you'd want to use `.prop()` - answer reworded to reflect that

Comment: i am curious to know whether u can use css to do this?